# g++ 9.2.1 (Linux) causes seg fault but Codeblocks on windows does not

Tags: c++, file-handling

The following simple code (binary file handling) runs fine on the compiler bundled with Codeblocks 17.12 (mingw32-g++) for Windows but gives a segmentation fault with g++ 9.2.1 for Linux (on Ubuntu 19.10):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    int x;
    string y;
};
int main()
{
    ofstream k;
    A m;
    m.x = 10;
    m.y = "Hello";
    k.open("file.dat", ios::binary);
    k.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&m), sizeof(A));
    k.close();
    ifstream i;
    A t;
    i.open("file.dat", ios::binary);
    i.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&t), sizeof(A));
    cout << t.x << " " << t.y;
    i.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, that minimal g++ on windows is forgiving me for but g++-Linux is not? Or have I discovered a bug?

Comment: `std::string` is the problem. Think about that.

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. Writing the memory where an object resides to a file is *not* proper serialization. Search for that term online to get further info.

Comment: You can only read or write raw objects if they are [POD types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) without pointers. `std::string` is basically a pointer to heap-allocated data and the size of the string (small string optimization aside), therefore you can't read or write raw `std::string` objects to file.

Comment: *Or have I discovered a bug?* -- A bug in the compiler?  No.  A bug in your code?  Yes.  Also, this can't work if you note the last argument to `write` and `read`.  The `sizeof(A)` never changes and is a compile-time value.  If that `std::string` member had a million characters in it, the `sizeof(A)` will not change.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Then, is there an explanation for why this works on windows before calling my code buggy?

Comment: @UtkarshGupta Undefined behavior is just that -- undefined.  That very same code may fail if you change compiler options.

Comment: Also, try the case I mentioned.  Make `y` a thousand characters instead of just 5.  You will see your code fail.  For example, `m.y = std::string(1000, 'x');`  Do you see 1,000 'x' characters in the output file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour.

You can't bytewise serialise a complex object like `std::string` like that.

The results of undefined behaviour can vary; on your Linux installation you're probably witnessing the "small string optimisation", where your string data is small enough to fit into a little in-place buffer. This avoids any dynamic memory which is causing a crash on Windows. Perhaps Windows is detecting the bad behaviour, or perhaps it has a smaller SSO buffer, or perhaps none at all!

But the code still has undefined behaviour either way.